# Save Folium Map as PNG to IOBytes For Use in PyDocx

Tags: python, folium

I'm using streamlit to build a web-app that can generate custom docx reports.  One element of the report needs to be a map.  To add additional complexity to the problem I need to run the app in a docker container so I can't save files locally and add them after.

I've had some success saving plotly figures into bytesIO objects and then sending them to pydocx documents but I'm struggling to repeat the success with maps.  The basecamp maps are poor quality and not fit for purpose so I've been using folium to map data.

In an ideal world my method would be something like this:

```
#pseudo code trying to use correct methods where possible
doc = docx.Document()
map = folium.Map(location = [51.421606, -0.067276], zoom_start = 12, returned_objects = [])
png = map.convert_to_png() #not a real method as far as i know
img = io.BytesIO(png)
doc.add_picture(img, width = Inches(6))
```

Comment: Why can't you save the images to a file and mount them into the container with a volume?

Comment: The user needs to be able to specify where the map is.  Then data can be added to the map and the user can generate a report document for their own use.